# Cross Platform SHA-1 Class

Tags: c++

I am looking for a platform independant SHA-1 class that does not use an underlying API such as Crypto.

I found this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2463/CSHA1-A-C-Class-Implementation-of-the-SHA-1-Hash-A

However it seems to use TCHAR and so forth which leads me to think it is Windows Only.

Thanks

Comment: wikipedia has pseudocode for sha1, it is fairly simple to implement in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code at: [SHA-1 Code](http://www.ipa.go.jp/security/rfc/RFC3174EN.html)

We are using this on an ARM7 based embedded processor.

You may want to search the web for "SHA1" and see what pops up.